# Convert content to text parsing JSON URL response

Tags: json, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch

I've got a url where the result is shown as below

```
    "playerInfo": {
        "059gh": {
            "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG",
            "status": "FA"
        },
        "04mr6": {
            "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG",
            "status": "FA"
        },
        "059fz": {
            "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG",
            "status": "FA"
        },
        "059fw": {
            "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG",
            "status": "FA"
        },
        "033b7": {
            "eligiblePos": "Flx3,Flx,Flx2,C",
            "status": "FA"
        },
        ...
```

I've got a function that tries to retrieve the player id and the eligiblePos
For ex : **059gh**  //  **Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG**

```
function getPlayerData() {
  var DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID = "xxxx"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var PlayerDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PlayerData");
  PlayerDataSheet.clearContents();
  var url = 'https://www.fantrax.com/fxea/general/getLeagueInfo?leagueId=' + leagueID;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(content);
  var playerKeys = Object.keys(data.playerInfo);
  PlayerDataSheet.appendRow(playerKeys)
  ...
```

The problem I've got is the results for **playerKeys** in my spreadsheet, tab "PlayerData", are shown as numbers and I want to convert to text.

Indeed 033b7 gets converted to 33b7
or 03e75 to 3E+75

I tried to cast to text but with no success

Comment: Try prepending a `'` before the data: like `'033b7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,
What I have done to solve the issue,
is to create a list (in cell A1) with "|" as separator

```
  var listplayer = playerKeys.join("|");
  PlayerDataSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(listplayer);
```

Then thanks to that page : [split google sheet keeping the character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77406103/split-google-sheet-keeping-the-character),
I split the result directly in another worksheet keeping the original text

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^|\|","|'"),"|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  let data = {playerInfo: {"059gh": { "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG", "status": "FA" },"04mr6": { "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG", "status": "FA" },"059fz": { "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG", "status": "FA" },"059fw": { "eligiblePos": "Flx3,G,Flx,Flx2,PG",  "status": "FA"},"033b7": { "eligiblePos": "Flx3,Flx,Flx2,C","status": "FA"}}};
  var playerKeys = Object.keys(data.playerInfo);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, playerKeys.length).setValues([playerKeys]).setNumberFormat("0.###############")
}
```