# split google sheet keeping the character

Tags: google-sheets, split, numbers

In google sheets
I've got the following result in cell A1
`059gh|04mr6|059fz|059fw|033b7|059fv|05293|059fy|059fx|03e75|`

I've used
`=transpose(split(A1,"|"))`

but it gives me as a result
059gh
04mr6
059fz
059fw
033b7
059fv
**5293**
059fy
059fx
**3E+75**

How can I fix this ? (I want to keep 05293 and 03e75)

I've tried regex with no great success

Comment: You must format the target cell as plain text. Otherwise, the numeric data are coerced to number format.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. And, I cannot know your other values. When this answer cannot be used for your other values, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","|'"),"|"))
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^|\|","|'"),"|"))
```

- It supposes that your sample value `059gh|04mr6|059fz|059fw|033b7|059fv|05293|059fy|059fx|03e75|` is put into cell "A1".
- When a value of `059gh|04mr6|059fz|059fw|033b7|059fv|05293|059fy|059fx|03e75|` is split by `|`, `05293` is used as a number value. It seems that this is the current specification. So, before each value is split, I added `'` to the top character of each value. I thought that by this modification, `05293` might be able to be used as a string value.

#### Testing:

When this formula is used to your sample input value `059gh|04mr6|059fz|059fw|033b7|059fv|05293|059fy|059fx|03e75|`, the following result is obtained.

[image]